# Generator.yml using DB value [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony1, backend

I'm new using symfony, and I can't seem to find a proper solution to my problem.

The thing is, I have a backend module with all the configuration for the website (sitename, items per page, default style). I want to configure the generator.yml file so in the list field I can set the value of max_per_page not as a static number but fetched from the database.

I know I could use php code in that file but since it's cached I don't think that'd be the best solution. My generator.yml file looks like this:

```
generator:
class: sfDoctrineGenerator
param:
model_class:           PodcastUsers
theme:                 admin
non_verbose_templates: true
with_show:             false
singular:              ~
plural:                ~
route_prefix:          podcast_users
with_doctrine_route:   true
actions_base_class:    sfActions

config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    max_per_page: 10;
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

Is there any way to initialize the max_per_page value from the code somewhere so if I change that number in the db it'd be instantly refreshed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately .yml files can be parsed as PHP so you can insert PHP code. No idea how you are going to store this max_per_page value, but you can create or edit an existing model file and add a method to retrieve the value, then include it in your yaml file. Following is demonstrative only:

```
class MyModelTable
{
    public static function getMaxPerPage($myId)
    {
        // Assuming doctrine ORM
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('MyTable mt')
            ->where('mt.id = ?', array($myId));

        $results = $q->fetchOne();

        return $results['max_per_page'];
    }
}

// Generator.yml
config:
  ...
  list:
    max_per_page: <?php echo MyModelTable::getMaxPerPage($someId) . PHP_EOL ?>
  filter: ~
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried that, but the problem is that the value of that max_per_page gets cached... so it won't change instantly in production server.
I found this link though: http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/symfony-admingenerator-sfdoctrinepager-pass-a-page-size

There it shows how to override the function getPagerMaxPerPage() in the moduleGeneratorConfiguration.class.php , which will do fair enough.

Thanks!